# How to Know the Progress of RAID1 Rebuild on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, raid, raid-1

I have just installed Windows 10 on my RAID1 array which has 2 disks. And I'm now doing some tests. I unplugged one disk and booted into the OS, then replugged it back, and restarted. Now I see the HDD LED is always on and I think it should be in the rebuild progress. But how can I know the progress of the rebuild?

EDIT: I'm using the built-in Intel RAID controller of my Gigabyte Z97 motherboard.

Comment: That depends on your RAID controller. So you need to provide more details.

Comment: There isn't a progress indicator with the hardware you have

Comment: So I have to watch the HDD LED along? I also notice that the disk usage shown in taskmgr is not always 100%. Are they related?

Answer (score 0):

There is almost certainly a software component to monitor the RAID status.  You will need to download it from the support page for your motherboard.  It will be called something like RAID monitor, or possibly just go by some generic name like 'storage technology'.

Comment: Didn't find one...